# Nservice bus send message under same unit-of-work

Tags: nservicebus, unit-of-work

I use Nservicebus 5 with RabbitMQ, and I want to send different messages to different queues under the same uow. Is it possible ?

```
       using (_NsbunitOfWork)
        {
            _NsbunitOfWork.Begin();

                 _busSms.Send(smsmessage);
                 _busOffer.Send(offermessage);
                 _busTrnx.Send(Trnxmessage);

            _NsbunitOfWork.Commit();
        }
```

Comment: Can you describe your scenario a bit, please?

Comment: It sounds like they want an all or none behavior for sending the messages to these different transports/queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish? I'm assuming you want to send messages to different queues, so that different applications can process these messages? In the documentation these are usually called [endpoints](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/endpoints/).

If you read the [routing documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing), you'll notice that the sender code should not be aware of where the message should be sent. This is what routing takes care of. So you could do multiple calls to `context.Send()` and NServiceBus would figure out where to send the message to.

Does that make sense? You could also try https://discuss.particular.net/ which is more suited for NServiceBus related discussions with multiple replies, or try support@particular.net